# How do I give the correct parameters without "&" or "*" to the called method?

Tags: c++

I am new here quite new to writing code in c++ and currently run into following problem:

I use the library wykobi which deals with geometry and solved many of my prior problems, but now I want to create a triangle using it and cant figure out how to call the required method correctly.

```
std::string x_str(argv[2]);
std::string y_str(argv[3]);
double x = atof(x_str.c_str());
double y = atof(y_str.c_str());
```

[...]

```
double x2;
x2 = double(orientation.direction.x)+angleRightx;
double y2;
y2 = double(orientation.direction.y)+angleRighty;
double x3;
x3 = double(orientation.direction.x)+angleLeftx;
double y3;
y3 = double(orientation.direction.y)+angleLefty;

wykobi::triangle<wykobi::Float,2> clip_boundry = wykobi::make_triangle<wykobi::Float,2>(&x,&y, &x2,&y2, &x3,&y3);
wykobi::polygon<wykobi::Float,2> clipped_polygon;
wykobi::algorithm::sutherland_hodgman_polygon_clipper<wykobi::point2d<wykobi::Float> >(clip_boundry,wykPG,clipped_polygon);
```

I tried something similar before creating a circle, which worked perfectly fine:

```
wykobi::circle<wykobi::Float> circle;
circle.x = x;
circle.y = y;
circle.radius = dist;
wykobi::polygon<wykobi::Float,2> clip_boundry = wykobi::make_polygon<wykobi::Float>(circle,100);
wykobi::polygon<wykobi::Float,2> clipped_polygon;
wykobi::algorithm::sutherland_hodgman_polygon_clipper<wykobi::point2d<wykobi::Float> >(clip_boundry,wykPG,clipped_polygon);
```

Now the problem on compiling is:

error: no matching function for call to 'make_triangle(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*)'

When I remove the ampersands:

```
wykobi::triangle<wykobi::Float,2> clip_boundry = wykobi::make_triangle<wykobi::Float,2>(x,y, x2,y2, x3,y3);
```

The error on comiling is:

error: no matching function for call to 'make_triangle(double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&)'

And finally the method I call looks like this:

```
template<typename T> inline triangle<T,2> make_triangle(const T& x1, const T& y1, const T& x2, const T& y2, const T& x3, const T& y3);
```

So I wonder what do I have to change to give the correct parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<wykobi::Float,2>` does not sound good. First, it is not double, second, 2 is not a template parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am still going through the answers, as they all seam to have a point that I should address. In addition I have an unrelated problem with my compiler, which I have to solve before handling this issue. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have at least the following issues:

1) Mixing up double with wykobi::Float.

2) You are passing two template parameters, whereas the function only expects one.

3) Template deduction could hopefully be done here.

Try this code:

```
wykobi::make_triangle(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

or

```
wykobi::make_triangle<wykobi::Float>(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

or

```
wykobi::make_triangle<double>(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

but make sure these parameters are wykobi::Float or double, respectively. Do not mix them up unless wykobi::Float is some kind of typedef.

Also, do not try passing addresses because this template function does not expect a pointer.

Answer (score 11):

The function `make_triangle<wykobi::Float..()` requires that you pass references to `wykobi::Float`, but instead, you are trying to pass variables of type `double`.

I don't know the library, but see if there is some explicit or implicit conversion from `double` to the `wykobi::Float` type

e.g.

```
wykobi::Float wx1 = x;
```

or

```
wykobi::Float wx1 = new wykobi::Float(x);
```

and then pass these to the `make_triangle` function.

Also, as per Lazlo's comment, the constant `2` does not appear valid for a template parameter - this should be a `type`, e.g. int.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the [wykobi headers](https://code.google.com/p/wykobi/source/browse/trunk/wykobi_math.hpp?r=5), it looks like `wykobi::Float` is a typedef to either `float` or `double`, depending on compiler options. And from your errors, I'd bet that it is `float`.

So your solution is to be consistent and use `wykobi::Float` instead of `double` everywhere, and/or compile the library with the define `WYKOBI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`.

Another option would be to call the function without specifying the template parameters, as the compiler will deduce them automatically. But then, if you are non consistent you will get strange errors when mixing `double` and `float`.

```
wykobi::triangle<double,2> clip_boundry =
        wykobi::make_triangle(x,y, x2,y2, x3,y3);
```

wich will be deduced as if:

```
wykobi::triangle<double,2> clip_boundry =
        wykobi::make_triangle<double>(x,y, x2,y2, x3,y3);
```

Note that the `2` is not a template argument for the function.